# Implementing nullable references for manual memory management

Tags: pointers, memory-management, runtime, reference-counting

The, uh, "legacy" [BlitzPlus programming language](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/_index_.php) has an interesting feature designed to make manual memory management "safe" for newbie programmers, compared to the dangling pointer problems they might potentially encounter in a language that expects them to manage raw pointers like C. When an object is deleted, all references to that object become references to `null`:

```
Local a.Foo = New Foo
Local b.Foo = a
Delete a
; at this point, b = null
```

How might one go about implementing such a system?

---

The original implementation uses hidden automatic reference counting. `Delete` doesn't actually free an object, it just sets an "identity" field to `null` - so in the above example, the variable b still points to the same object it did before but that object has been tagged as equal to `null` for the purposes of comparison. The memory itself is not released until the object's hidden reference count reaches zero. (If this strikes you as an odd decision, it probably was: the language's successor ditched explicit `Delete`, and just used the reference counting system and called it a GC.)

There are a few things about this design that strike me as a bit off:

1. Conventional wisdom holds that refcounting is slow. It also wastes a *whole word* of memory (the horror!).
2. As far as I can see, refcounting is incompatible, or only poorly compatible, with multithreading (I think the logic of the developer was that "multithreading will never catch on").
3. The manual `Delete` operator doesn't actually manually manage memory anyway! (Although it arguably provides *slightly* more control than leaving it entirely to the refcounter, since it can break cycles and eagerly decrement the counts of owned objects.)

Anyway BlitzPlus is now open-source, and as a result I want to try my hand at implementing it since that's allowed (for the fun of the challenge). If this were a brand new language design, the obvious answer would be "make it garbage collected", but it isn't: the existing language has `Delete` so an implementation has to work with that.

---

Is there any obvious way to implement this that doesn't have the drawbacks and/or smells of the above, i.e. perhaps without refcounts at all? (I mean I could have a full tracing GC in the background, but that seems silly. Even in the context of implementing a dead language.) Is the original strategy actually as bad as it looks? Is there a way to get "true" manual management - i.e. free-on-`Delete` - while still nulling all references?

Comment: Refcounting is not free, and the only known way to make its throughput equal top-tier tracing GCs is to introduce lazy, tracing elements. But it's easier to implement (both manually and in an optimizing compiler), and the per-object word that it takes up would also be taken in almost all tracing GC designs. Making it multi-threaded is indeed hard, in the sense that the only safe and remotely easy way is to make all increment and decrement operations atomic, which is another performance hit.